# magento Default DHL Shipping Method will be good or i should purchase any extension for DHL shipping?

Tags: magento-1.9

i am using first time DHL shipping so Please suggest me I Should use Default DHL shipping method or purchase any extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to check this [article](https://www.xadapter.com/setting-up-magento-2-0-default-dhl-shipping-extension/) to know how the default DHL Shipping works.
 If you are ok with default functionality go with it or go for purchasing extension. 
If possible Share your requirement clearly. So that, I will be able to help you.